# Is this a bug in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome

I installed `gnome-shell` a few months ago. This is the package information:

```
$ dpkg-query --show gnome-shell
gnome-shell 3.5.2+git20120615.7524210d-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1
```

I use Ubuntu at work everyday so this is really annoying because I have to restart everytime. Here's the situation: after 4-6 hours of work my Chromium window starts to look like this (when maximize):

[image]

Tab titles, bookmarks and buttons disappear (I have to hover so I can actually see them). Tab content turns black (again, hover).

First I thought it was a Chromium issue and minimizing the window seems to solve the problem (for a while):

[image]

After 30-60 minutes the problems persists and then I have to minimize even more. Then, I realized Chromium was not the only one. This is geany:

[image]

Same thing with buttons and left panel.

I was wondering if this is some kind of known `gnome-shell` issue and if this is the case, how can I solve it?

Thanks

**Edit:**

From `gnome-tweak-tool`

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Problem persist even with official `gnome-shell` PPA

**P.S.** Please don't say "use Unity"

Comment: using any custom gtk theme?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: It's probably best to just report it as a bug to find if there's a duplicate.

Comment: @Web-E updated my question

Comment: Not use Unity, but use the official supported 3.4 gnome-shell; if you want to use bleeding-edge experimental PPA versions, well, this just comes with the territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **an unofficial unsupported version** of gnome-shell from Gnome 3.5 from the "ricotz" PPA. File a bug *with the PPA maintainer*.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now I'm using official GNOME ppa. Thanks